# In sql2000 through sql 2008r2 is it ok to use bigint for primary key and foreign keys on all tables in a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I want to standardize my database to a consistent primary key because of a move from sql 2000 to sql 2008r2.  Is using bigint a good way to go for use with primary keys and foreign keys and can it be auto incremented by 1 when a new row is added?  Should I use int instead of bigint?  Also are there any problem with ints or bigints when going form sql2000 to sql2008r2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BIGINT` is probably safest, but for a given entity you should use the largest number you need rather than standardize on the largest number possible across all entities.

For an `IDENTITY` column on an `Employees` table, for example, `BIGINT` just might be overkill. Are you going to have more than 2 billion employees, or write code that tries to create an employee 2 billion times but fails and rolls back every time? Probably `SMALLINT` is fine (32,000+) unless you're dealing with a very large company.

For other tables where you just don't know how many rows you'll get, again, `BIGINT` is probably safest. I would hope that you would have some idea based on the entity and the business to be able to lump a table into either a "might get > 2 billion rows" bucket, or a "definitely won't get > 2 billion rows" bucket. For the latter, you can break those down further, if you want. I've seen many systems with smallish lookup tables where the `IDENTITY` was defined as `SMALLINT` or even `TINYINT` - for those sizes I'd rather just standardize on `INT`. Personal preference, kind of like using `CHAR` for strings that may vary in size but will always be < 5 characters.

A `BIGINT` is 8 bytes, an `INT` is 4 bytes. It's only double the size but this can become a big performance factor on large tables, depending on index structure, number of rows per page, how often you delete, and a host of other factors. Unfortunately the largest tables, where this really does come into play, are also the ones that probably require the possibility that they will get > 2 billion values.

`BIGINT` is available in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head with performance.  I would hate to have to have to wait twice as long for a query to run when I'm trying to make things as efficient as possible.

Comment: +1 Great advice. I do alot of data warehouse design and the decision of int size is highly dependent upon prediction. If you can't imagine more than 200 possible values, use tinyint (an alter table to smallint will take milliseconds if you happen to hit 255 records). The smaller the type, the faster the performance.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on what your needs are...do you see the identity columns going higher than INT? If so, use BIGINT. Otherwise it makes no difference.

Comment: Its really rare to have more than 2 billion rows of an item in any of my table for the next 30 years. But going to bigint for all of them should make the primary keys the same type.

Comment: Does it make any difference on programs like asp, asp.net, java on how I access these tables, perform unions or joins?

Comment: If none of your tables will have more than 2 billion rows, why not use INT everywhere instead of BIGINT? If one or two tables have that potential, I'd still rather make those the exception than try to fit the exception across everyone else. Once you've designed the table, there are very few spots where the developer will care whether it is an int or bigint.

Comment: Sure, some languages do need to know the type. But are you also going to make all varchar columns the same width? Your code needs to know how long a string can be, your forms need validation for things like maxlength, etc. Saving developers from the burden of actually knowing your data model because 1 or 2 tables do not fit some mold is not worth the inefficiencies it brings about in other areas, IMHO. YMMV.

Comment: To clarify, your app code will not care about things like passing in a query that joins PK = FK, whether those are int or bigint (that logic should be in stored procedures anyway). They will care if you are defining parameters and passing values in, or dealing with the output.